# Integrate $(\sin x)^{\sin x}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Is there any way to calculate $$\int{(\sin x)^{\sin x}\,dx}$$

I do this steps:
[image]

Comment: Then I have to integrate this function?? ,is that right ?

Comment: You've got an error: $dy \neq dx$

Comment: How do you plan to get the primitiv function of $y$ when you (try) to calculate the primitive of $\ln y$?

Comment: This does not look like a function that has a elementary antiderivative. You might be able to get a series solution though.

Comment: You need to learn math markup!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there any way to calculate $\displaystyle\int{(\sin x)^{\sin x}\,dx}$ ?

No. See [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)) and the [Risch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm).

Comment: (Not OP) I only know up to Calc 2, how is this theorem applied to this integral?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$\int(\sin x)^{\sin x}~dx$

$=\int(e^{\ln\sin x})^{\sin x}~dx$

$=\int e^{\sin x\ln\sin x}~dx$

$=\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{\sin^nx(\ln\sin x)^n}{n!}dx$

$=\int\left(1+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{\sin^nx(\ln\sin x)^n}{n!}\right)dx$